# How do you check systemd update content?

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, upgrade, updates

I am thinking of updating an Ubuntu server, and was wondering whether to update systemd or not. However, I am not certain how to inspect the contents of the systemd update. The output of `apt list --upgradable` shows:

```
systemd/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu19 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu17]
systemd-sysv/xenial-updates 229-4ubuntu19 amd64 [upgradable from: 229-4ubuntu17]
```

How do I inspect the contents of these updates to make sure I'm ok with what they are doing to my system?

Apologies if this is a basic question for the advanced Ubuntines here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as **Major** (here it is `229`) and **Minor** (here it is `4`)   version numbers does not change, you can install update without thinking about the bug. **Maintenance** version number (here it is `19`) only includes bug fixes.

Also, I suppose that, what you are looking for is **Changelog**. It will show you what changes are applied in different versions. The output of `apt changelog systemd`:

```
systemd (229-4ubuntu19) xenial; urgency=medium

  * debian/extra/units/systemd-resolved.service.d/resolvconf.conf: partially
    revert, by removing ExecStart|StopPost lines, as these are not needed on
    xenial and generate warnings in the journal. (LP: #1704677)

 -- Dimitri John Ledkov <xnox@ubuntu.com>  Mon, 17 Jul 2017 17:00:42 +0100

systemd (229-4ubuntu18) xenial; urgency=medium

  * debian/extra/units/systemd-resolved.service.d/resolvconf.conf: if resolved
    is going to be started, make sure this blocks network-online.target.
    (LP: #1673860)
  * networkd: cherry-pick support for setting bridge port's priority
    (LP: #1668347)
  * Cherrypick upstream commit to enable system use kernel maximum limit for
    RLIMIT_NOFILE isntead of hard-coded (low) limit of 65536. (LP: #1686361)
  * Cherrypick upstream patch for platform predictable interface names.
    (LP: #1686784)
  * resolved: fix null pointer dereference crash (LP: #1621396)
  * Cherrypick core/timer downgrade message about random time addition
    (LP: #1692136)
  * SECURITY UPDATE: Out-of-bounds write in systemd-resolved (LP: #1695546)
    - CVE-2017-9445
  * Cherry-pick subset of patches to introduce infinity value in logind.conf
    for UserTasksMax (LP: #1651518)

 -- Dimitri John Ledkov <xnox@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 05 Jul 2017 13:45:48 +0100
```

Comment: Please consider to comment why you **downvote**, if you are going to...